# permutations - letter arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many different linear arrangements are there of the letters A,B,C,D,E,F for which
>
> (a) A and B are next to each other and C and D are also next to each other?

I got 2!*2!*2!,  but I don’t know how to proceed after that

Comment: Suppose $AB$ occurs as a block (in that order) and that $CD$ also occurs as a block (in that order).  How many arrangements are there then?

Comment: Since A and B have to be next to each other, consider them one "package" , AB or BA. Then, the same for C and D, making CD or DC. Now, one such arrangement can be
$$
(AB)(E) (DC) (E)(F)
$$
Can you now visualize the different arrangement?

Comment: (I accidentally put two $E$'s there ... but you got the point!)

Comment: yeah, but I don't get it completely,.

Answer (score 1):

Group $A$ and $B$ together, and $C$ and $D$ together.

So, there are now $4$ elements:

$$\{A,B\}$$
$$\{C,D\}$$
$$E$$
$$F$$

which can be arranged in $4!$ ways, but for each of these arrangements, the $\{A,B\}$ set can generate two different arrangements (since we can write $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$) and similarly for $\{C,D\}$. Thus we have $4\times 4!= 96 $ arrangements.

Comment: But what about E and F getting arranged among themselves. shouldn't we multiply by one more 2!?

Comment: That is already satisfied with the $4!$ arrangements.

Comment: If so, then why are we doing the 4 ways for AB and CD , isnt that also included in the 4!ways?

Comment: The $4!$ counts orderings of the four entities {A,B}, {C,D},{E},{F}. When you look at orderings of the letters, multiply by $2!*2!*1!*1!$ to count them all.

Comment: Suppose $AB$=$G$ and $CD$=$H$ are both one element, so we have $4!$ ways to arrange $E,F, G$ and $H$. Then instead of writing $AB$ we can have $BA$ and instead of $CD$ we can have $DC$.

Comment: okay guys , understood